# How to delete data from firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Collection called `postsCollection` and inside there are documents which I want to delete each by each.

Collection:

[image]

code:

```
delete () {
  fb.postsCollection.doc().delete().then(function() {
      console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
  }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
  });
}
```

I don't know how to define the `doc()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to delete any document from the collection you have to pass that document's uid.
And then call the `delete()` method.

```
var postsRef = db.collection('posts');
var query = postsRef.where('content', '==', 'color..').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        var deleteDoc = db.collection('posts').doc(doc.id).delete();
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

You can check where condition a unique field. Otherwise it will delete all documents having 'content' equaTo 'color..'. Similarly you can use various other clauses like >, <, >= etc.

Comment: and what is doc(uid), how would you like to definde uid?

Comment: If you want to delete current user data then you can gey its uid by calling auth.getCurrentUser().getUid(). Where auth is a reference to FirebaseAuth

Comment: If you want to delete a particular post you have to specify a condition based on which document can be deleted. Eg: in sql db we write Delete from employee where id = 1; Similary if you have its uid you can pass. Else first you have to retrieve its document by using any condition. Eg firestore.collection("posts").whereEqualTo("createdOn", specificDate).get() and then get this document uid and pass it in calling delete method.

Comment: yes sounds great, can you update your code in your answer, please.

Comment: but not perfectly, I am in stuck with .where(...)

Comment: Whats the problem with where condition ?

Comment: so I can delete the files but all and not one

Comment: I have already mention in my answer therw must be some unique condtion so that particular document should be deleted. As I have for a demo purpose using content. So, there might be the case if every content value is color.. it will delete all documents. Try to edit the value of content from color.. to something else from the console and then execute. Then it will only delete that document. So, you should use some unique condition depending on your logic and use. Here for a demo purpose I am using content

Comment: okay yes, this will work, but which one should I take. I mean I cannot take content or createdOn or username because these values are more than one in use

Comment: I think createdOn can be a unique field. Beacuse timestamp is upto seconds. And a user can create only one post at a given time stamp. Moreover you can better decide what can a unique value based on what the project is related to and what are other collections and how you plan the database structure.

Comment: how can I do this with the createdOn field in where(...)

Comment: In order to do that you must have the complete timestamp of the document you want to delete and then you can use where('createdOn' == '30 August.....') i.e. complete timestamp. Whatever field you put condition you must have its value to make the comparison.

Comment: The best approach is to delete a document using uid, as uid is unique for every post. Moreover id depends on your implementation how you are deleting the post. If you are using Recycler view and deleting the post on click of its item then you can get each document uid in onBind method. Then you can easily compare it with existing documents using where condition.

Comment: @Raj could you please provide a function for the new version of swift? this code does not work any more

Comment: From the above code, is there a specific function that doesn't work or the complete code is not working @Alex ?

Comment: The complete code. I need your implemetation for the same problem, but i does not work

Comment: Is it possible to chat with you for the same reason ?

Answer (score 1):

To delete a document, you will need to know its ID. This means that, if you don't know the IDs in a collection, you will have to read the documents from the collection first to delete them.

In code that would look like this:

```
fb.postsCollection.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ref.delete().then(function() {
      console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: this will delete all documents from the collection at once, but I want that I can delet e one and not all by the same time.

Comment: This code actually deletes them one by one: each call to `doc.ref.delete()` deletes one document. If that's not what you want, can you describe your "I want to delete each by each" comment in a different way?

Comment: So I want this what you called in your answer above. But it did not work by me, it deletes all documents e.g I had 3 documents then I click the button with the function and after this, all documents are deleted in the postsCollection.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed precisely what this code does: it each document from the collection, one by one. Given your question ("I have a Collection and inside there are documents, which I want to delete each by each.") that is what I thought you wanted. What do you want to accomplish instead?

Comment: No this what you write is that what I want but it does not work

Comment: In each document, there is an image that is inserted in the web page and each has a button to delete the current image. I click on Delete and all documents of the entire collection will be deleted. But I want that only the current picture is deleted.

Comment: That is quite a lot of additional information that is completely absent from your original question. Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case should probably include something about how you show the image in the HTML. You'll also have to pass something from the document that is rendered into the HTML, such as its ID. Then when the user clicks on the image, you can get the ID from the HTML, and delete the document based on that.

Comment: okay yes my mistake sorry, but I already found exactly this what I want:

Comment: https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-cloud-firestore/ everthing I wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete a document once you have a Document Reference to it. To get that you must first execute the query, then loop over the Query Snapshot and finally delete each Document Snapshot based on its ref.

```
var doucumentid = db.collection('posts').where('id','==',post.id);
doucumentid_query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
doc.ref.delete();
});
});
```